# How to capture the output of multiple commands run in docker separately?

Tags: bash, docker

I use docker to run a bash file which has multiple commands in it. One per line.

Is there a way to capture the output of those commands separately? I want to have something like this command has this output, this other command has this other output and so on.

Or run separate commands in same docker image? Maybe this could be a way to separate the output of those commands.

Comment: how are you capturing the output of these commands currently?

Comment: Did you find a solution without Docker ? Is redirecting the output to a file what you want (perhaps use `set -v` first) ?

Comment: I'd recommend splitting this into multiple containers rather than running all the commands in a single container.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that all commands depend one on the other. So I have something like "git clone...", then next line "npm install", then next line "npm test", etc... So if they run in different containers it would not work as expected right? As if I don't have the first git clone then I can't run npm install.

Comment: Or it it possible to run each step in its own container and keep the data in the host machine? Like step1 (git clone in /tmp/something) then step2 (npm install in new container but also on same host folder /tmp/something so still having the data produced by first container) then (npm test - 3rd container but same dir) and then cleanup?

Comment: An example Dockerfile would be helpful. I don't understand the problem. Doesn't sound like these commands are long running (eg git clone, npm install). Why don't you just put them in a shell script and run them as a single command from your Dockerfile?

Comment: It sounds like you are running a build inside of your container. That's either done with a Dockerfile and the `docker build` command, or if you're making a CI solution, setup something like Jenkins and point it to a docker build slave. Each command would be a separate command in Jenkins and it would track the output.

Comment: I'm trying to do a DIY tool like https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines for academic pourposes and i've seen they run the commands as a single bash file while they can separate the output in individual commands. For example this is the command they would run

Comment: `+ docker run -t --entrypoint=/bin/bash --memory=4096m -e BUILD_DIR=/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build -v /tmp/bashScript7489111525137375193.sh:/tmp/bashScript7489111525137375193.sh:ro -v build-volume-d0a5ade7-7969-4349-861c-61314bf48836:/opt/atlassian/pipelines:rw -w /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build --label com.atlassian.pipelines.agent="f27d5a2fd8a4" "atlassian/pipelines-dvcstools:latest" -i /tmp/bashScript7489111525137375193.sh
+ umask 000
`

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how they can run a single bash file (which contain multiple commands but then parse the output and separate it in multiple commands. From what I see they make use of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#Field_separators (0x1D - char / Group Separator) But nor sure how they achieve this.